# Spring MVC - Thymeleaf - Map Controller just to replace html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm doing a Web App with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.
In the Web page, I have a menu with final link mapped on controller.
I need to have url of the link but without redirect to any file or other page, just stay on home and replace part of HTML.

HTML LINK

```
<li class="px-nav-item" key="xxx" value="xxx">
<a href="/<**url**>"><span class="px-nav-label">xxxx</span></a></li>
```

CONTROLLER JAVA

```
@RequestMapping(path="/<**url**>", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getDataTorneo(ModelMap model) {
    ...
    return ???;
}
```

HTML TO REPLACE

```
<div th:??="yyy:: yy"></div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just a part of html to be updated then, ajax can be used as follows

```
<script>
  function getDataTorneo(){
      $.ajax({
             url: '<**your url**>',
             type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                  var contentHtml="";  
                  for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                     var attr1Value = response[i]['attr1'];
                     var attr2Value = response[i]['attr2'];
                     contentHtml = //form html as how it needs to be rendered.
                  }
                  $("#contentDiv").html(contentHtml); 
             }
       });
  }
</script>
...
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getDataTorneo()"><span class="px-nav-label">xxxx</span></a></li>
...

<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Before reading the answer, I had already adopted this solution. I prefer the fact of reloading the HTML and not the whole page, even so I lose the history and I can't back in the browser.
I was wondering if there was any function of Spring / Thymeleaf that would allow this, without redirect, directly